# Randomly getting 502 Bad Gateway response from AWS API Gateway after changing Lambda runtime from Node 8.x to Node 12.x

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

As NodeJS 8.x runtime on AWS Lambda is EOL, we moved our staging environment for our REST API to NodeJS 12.x..

Now we noticed, that at some random times request from frontend web app to API Gateway fails with 502. Usually this happens after API is idle for some time (few minutes). Mostly this happens for OPTIONS or HEAD requests, but this is probably because it is first request after some idle time. 
Any subsequent requests to API are working OK. Even if you refresh the website, all request go through with no problem.

I can't find any logs on Lambda.

API gateway log:

```
"error":  "Internal server error", "ErrorDetail": " "Internal server error"", "errorValidation": "-", "errorResponseType": "INTEGRATION_FAILURE"
```

Also we got same issues on rumtime NodeJS 10.x, but not on NodeJs 8.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we found the bug - it was in the code. :)

After some time, we found the Lambda logs on Cloud Watch that matched API Gateway's logs, and we saw some database timeouts. We are still investigating the details, but the issue was with express middleware for logging.

It was accessing the database even on OPTIONS and HEAD requests and before database connection was ensured to be alive. The problem may be connected with database socket timeout and Lambda life span. However simple try-catch around logging middleware apparently fixed the issue.

We are still not sure, why error was not happening on production with Node 8. Traffic was probably high enough to keep database connection open.

Thank you guys for all the help.

Comment: I am running into the same issue I think. Did you get to the bottom of it?

Answer (score 0):

let's see, there could be three things based on the information that you have provided:

1. Lambda function is supposed to return a JSON response as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html
2. other option would be IAM limitations.
3. Or lambda send a JSON that had a body parameter containing the escaped JSON data, like this:

```
 {
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "[\"aaa\",\"ccc\",\"ggg\",\"bbb\",\"ddd\"]"
 }
```

UPDATE:

You are receiving the errors on OPTION & HEAD operations which are pre-flight calls from the browser for CORS check.

What I did was:

The browser doing a pre-flight OPTIONS call DOES INDEED make it all the way to the back end. Witness the following:

```
{"result":"-err","number":1,"message":"The quantity and/or type of parameters provided is incorrect."}
```

What you see there is the response I receive to Chrome's OPTIONS pre-flight call. It is my custom ErrorMessage handler in my node app complaining that you've run the app without giving it the proper inputs. The pre-flight OPTIONS call doesn't POST any JSON (obviously), so the app gets pissed off.

I don't think its going to effect your application in whole but then there could be a solution to the problem from AWS API GATEWAY side.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it. However, as I described, the error is happening randomly. Subsequent request to same endpoint with same parameters will pass.

Comment: Updated the answer for more closer view to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds also like the cold start of lambdas
[Cold Starts in AWS Lambda](https://mikhail.io/serverless/coldstarts/aws/)

Check maybe if something may increase the cold start time of a lambda.

Comment: I was thinking in this direction, but I believe that request waits for lambda to start. The error response seems instant.

Comment: From the documentation : The gateway response for an integration failed error. If the response type is unspecified, this response defaults to the DEFAULT_5XX type.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/supported-gateway-response-types.html
Could you try to specify response type?